# ftplib.error_perm: 550 MLST type; not implemented

Tags: python, runtime-error, ftplib

I write a small FTP client. 
Here is such a code,

```
import ftplib
import sys
import easygui

ftp = ftplib.FTP('192.168.0.1', 'Artem','1204')
a = ftp.mlsd(facts=['type'])
print(a)
print(next(a))
```

I do not understand why it does not work tell me who knows. There is an error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/User/Desktop/Untitled-1.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(next(a))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ftplib.py", line 590, in mlsd
    self.sendcmd("OPTS MLST " + ";".join(facts) + ";")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ftplib.py", line 273, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ftplib.py", line 246, in getresp
    raise error_perm(resp)
ftplib.error_perm: 550 MLST type; not implemented
```

What should I do to make it work

Comment: The server doesn't implement the requested functionality.

Comment: What should I do to make it work